# writing 2048 game using c language

Tags: c

I'm writing a simple game 2048 in c language.
The pull left, pull right, pull up and pull down command is done.
However, the most important part, i think, which is terminating the program when there is no room to generate a new random number and pull the number.
Also i can't make the game board not generating a new number when there is no room to combine the same number and no room to pull the number.

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



if (gen_num == 0) {
            row = rand() % 4;
            column = rand() % 4;
            if (board[row][column] == 0) {
                board[row][column] = ((rand() % 2) + 1) * 2;

            }
        }
    }
    valid_move = 0;
    gen_num = 0;


    cmd = read_command();
    if (cmd == 1){
        pull_left(board);
    }
    if (cmd == 2){
        pull_right(board);
    }
    if (cmd == 3){
        pull_up(board);
    }
    if (cmd == 4){
        pull_down(board);
    }
    if (cmd == 5){
        printf("bye :(\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (cmd < 1 || cmd>5){
        printf("[error] command is between 1 and 5\n\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (board[i][j] == check_move[i][j])
                valid_move++;
        }
    }

    printf("Valid_move = %d\n\n", valid_move);

    if (valid_move >= 15){
        printf("[Error] Invalid direction!!!\n\n");
        gen_num = 1;
    }
```

pull_up, pull_down, pull_left, pull_right are the functions that i have set before the main function

Comment: Would you mind posting [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Just for the hell of it [here's a C implementation of 2048 for the TI](https://gist.github.com/Siguza/2ef468405d97c559fc88154585d63cf0) that I did 2 years back. It's nowhere near an answer, but maybe it'll help you in some regard. If anything, the `move()` function should be of most interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't complete, but from the looks of it you might end up not plaing a new tile at all, especially if the board is already very crowded. You should try to randomly place the tile as long as your position is invalid.

Of course, if there isn't any valid position, you will try over and over without success, so you should test whether the board is full, i.e. whether all tiles are non-zero.

You can combine plecing a new tile and checking whether the board is full. Instead of probing the board repeatedly, create a list of valid tiles and then pick one. If the list of valid tiles is empty, end the game.

A function that does this might look loike this:

```
int place_tile()
{
    int pos[16];
    int npos = 0;
    int i, j, p;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (board[j][i] == 0) pos[npos++] = j*4 + i;
        }
    }

    if (npos == 0) return 0;      // no more space

    p = pos[rand() % npos];
    j = p / 4;
    i = p % 4;

    board[j][i] = (rand() % 2) ? 2 : 4;
    return 1;
}
```

The return value indicates whether a tile was successfully placed (1) or not (0).